# continueUserActivity method not get called if app running in background

Tags: ios, objective-c, deep-linking, ios-universal-links

I am working on a big project written in Objective C and stuck in iOS Universal Link process. Universal Link works fine if the app is not running in the background, called continueUserActivity method and do as expected. But if the app is running in the background, hit the Universal Link, it opens the app as well as call willContinueUserActivityWithType method but continueUserActivity method not get called.

I don’t know why this happening. I test Universal Links in another project, everything is ok and works fine. But in my main project continueUserActivity not get called.

iOS version 11.4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is the `NSUserActivity` object of `UIApplication` becomes nil. That's why the`continueUserActivity` method not getting called. To fix the problem initialise `NSUserActivity` and set its delegate inside the `willContinueUserActivityWithType` method.

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application willContinueUserActivityWithType:(nonnull NSString *)userActivityType {

application.userActivity = [[NSUserActivity alloc] initWithActivityType:userActivityType];
application.delegate = self;

return true;
```

}

I don't know whether its a proper way, but it works for me.

Comment: I am running into the same issue but with Scene delegate. I have tried the same approach but without luck. Maybe someone would have any ideas?

Comment: @TarasLeskiv I have encountered the same issue and also used the Scene delegate. Did you resolved your problem?

Comment: @MichaelYuan yes, I now use `onOpenURL { url in .. }` on the view and it works as intended (Using SwiftUI) -- I have abandoned using the scene delegate.